# ispalindrome C, problems with checking space

Tags: c, string, function, palindrome

I am writing a function to check if a string of character is a palindrome.
e.g. aba, abba, a ba, a   ba, a nut for a jar of tuna. 
Abba isn't palindrome and " "(odd space) and "  "(double space) aren't.

```
int is_palindrome(const char string[]) {

  // This implementation is only partly correct
  int string_length = length(string);
  int i = 0, j = string_length - 1;
  for (i = 0; i < j + 1; i++, j--) {
    while (string[i] == ' ') {
      i = i + 1;
    }
    while (string[j] == ' ') {
      j = j - 1;
    }
    if (string[i] == ' ' && string[j] == ' ') {
      break;
    }

    if (string[i] != string[j]) {
      return 0;
    }
  }
  return 1;
}
```

*However, my real problem is that this function cannot check either oddspace and doublespace, and I cannot see where I am wrong.*

Comment: A debugger would make it *much* easier to discover the problem. Especially for this problem, where single-stepping would dovetail *perfectly* with discovering where things go off the rails.

Comment: If it's partially correct, it's wrong

Comment: I also don't see where you actually compare the *characters* of `string[i]` and `string[j]`. You went through a lot of work to find `i` and `j`. Comparing those efforts against the only conditions you *know* cannot be true because they were the very conditions that broke your loops above seems unproductive.

Comment: Sorry about the confusing sentence "this implementation is only partially correct" I forget to delete this line. The function was partly given and I wrote more codes to complete it.

Comment: the if function compares the characters if they same, the loop continues until returns 0; if they differ, the function will return 1. To check the space, I added the if function, the one with break, however, this seems wrong.

Comment: `while (string[j] == ' ') {
      j = j - 1;
  }` can make `j < 0`.  Then `string[j]` is UB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of problems.  Firstly, the test for whether `string[i] == ' '` and `string[j] == ' '` is pointless.  The previous lines have guaranteed that they won't be spaces; if they were, you would have skipped over them.

You also have a problem with the way you decrement j--you never check to ensure you aren't running off the beginning of the string.  I think the easiest way to handle it is to not allow i to increment past j, and not allow j to decrement past i.

I don't understand what you mnean about the odd space and double space not being palindromes means.  You ignore spaces in palindromes (otherwise "a nut for a jar of tuna" wouldn't be one).  Is it that there must be at least one non-space character for it to be judged a palindrome?  I'd just add a boolean and set it at the bottom of the for() loop to show you had at least one non-space character and base your final return value on that boolean.

Comment: Thanks, your first point makes a lot of sense to me. I just added one more if function after while i loop and it checks if i-1 == j, if yes, then it is not palindrome since all characters are space.